# Clarification of the topology lemma "Any continuous and open injection of the open disk extends over the circle"

Tags: general-topology, functions, notation

My elementary topology 1 class last semester used the book "Topology:  Point-Set and Geometric" by Paul Schick, and covered through the end of chapter 8.  I am working through the rest of the book on my own, and I came across the following lemma in chapter 10 on the classification of surfaces:

> **Lemma 10.3.1** Any continuous and open injection of the open unit disk into a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ extends over the circle.  That is, if  $ f \colon B = B_1(\vec{0})_{\mathfrak{U}^2} \rightarrow X_{\tau} $, with $ X_{\tau} \subset \mathbb{R}^n_{\mathfrak{U}^2}$, is a continuous and open injection, then $f$ extends to a continuous injection of the closed unit disk $\overline{f} \colon Cl(B) = D^2 \rightarrow X $.

In the Hint at how to proceed with a proof, the book states:

"Hint:  If $x \in S^1 = \partial B$, then there exists a sequence of points $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset B$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.  Define $\overline{f}(x)$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$.  Show $f$ is continuous and $1-1$."

My first question is: Why does the extension $\overline{f}$ still have to have codomain X (can't it be larger than X)?  First, consider the notational examples $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-2,\infty)$.  Both are correct (at least in the majority of notations I have seen from most authors, including Schick) for the function f defined by $f(x) = x^2$ where the domain is all reals.

Now back to this lemma in particular, just because every element of the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is in B doesn't mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \in B$.  In fact, the lemma itself is using the fact that the limit may lie in the set B or in the boundary of B.  Since B is open, the two sets or disjoint.  Therefore if we define $\overline{f}(x)$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$, then for $x \in \partial B$, $f(x) \notin B$, and then we may have also $f(x) \notin X$.

For example, let the function $f$ be defined as $f(x) = x$.  Then $f(B) = B$, and we can write $f \colon B \rightarrow B$, but $\overline{f}(Cl(B)) = \overline{f}(D^2) = D^2 \supset B$, then the statement: $\overline{f} \colon Cl(B) = D^2 \rightarrow B $ is incorrect.

So is the notation used in the lemma from the book simply incorrect?  Or is the lemma instead supposed to mean that it holds for some choice of $X$?  I realize this may be notational nit-picking, but it seems rather important to me distinguish the precise extent of what the lemma is claiming.

My second question is hopefully shorter:  The lemma states that "$ X_{\tau} \subset \mathbb{R}^n_{\mathfrak{U}^2}$", but if X is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n_{\mathfrak{U}^2}$, then isn't $\tau = \mathfrak{U}^2$ or simply the subspace topology?

Comment: Thus lemma is false already in the case of maps into the plane.

Comment: Clearly it should say that $\overline f:D^2\to\operatorname{cl}X$. What is $\mathfrak{U}_2$? The topology induced by the Euclidean metric (or uniformity)? If so, then yes, $\tau$ should be just the subspace topology.

Comment: The lemma is false: the extension need not to be one to one.

Comment: So if the lemma stated $Cl(X)$ rather than X, and if the hint only stated "continuous" and not also "1-1", then everything would be correct, right?

Comment: @user334137: No, this would be still wrong. Did the book also say "uniformly continuous"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, but to understand it you need some complex analysis.  Let $U$ be the domain in the complex plane bounded by the **[Warsaw circle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle)** $W$:

[image]

Then $U$ is bounded and simply connected. Let $f: D\to U$ denote the **[Riemann mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)**, i.e. the (essentially) unique conformal mapping. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism to its image. However, $f$ does not admit a continuous extension to the boundary circle since, otherwise, such extension would define a continuous mapping $g: S^1\to W=g(S^1)$. It would then follow that $W$ is [**locally connected**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space), but $W$ is not locally connected. qed

I am now puzzled by what the author of the book had in mind. I think, the lesson here is that you cannot always trust to what is written in textbooks.